# bigvideo.js don't work on Opera browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, background

I use this script [bigvideo.js](http://dfcb.github.com/BigVideo.js/) but don't work on Opera browser, can you suggest a solution?

I used this script to run it in firefox.

```
$(function() {
    var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
    BV.init();
    BV.show('vids/river.mp4', {altSource:'vids/river.ogv'});
});
```

There is something for it to work also on opera browser? I also created a webm video. Then I'd like use it in loop mode on any browsers. thanks

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: no error just don't work because the mp4 video file don't is supported of Opera browser (it use webm video file) like to firefox infact in the script there is a variation for it  use ogv video file, i'd like to do the same instruction for opera but it don't work

Comment: maybe it is possible to add a rule to jquery to load different video file only for opera browser?

Answer (score 0):

The maker of bigvideo.js had this to say on the issue:
https://github.com/dfcb/BigVideo.js/issues/3
Sadly isn't a real solution as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

The post is older but the first match on websearch. Here is a short opera-solution:

```
$(function() {
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://example.org/video/video-js.swf";
    var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
    BV.init();
    if (Modernizr.touch) {
        BV.show('http://example.org/video/alternative.jpg');
    } else if (/opera/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())){
        BV.show('http://example.org/video/myVideo.oggtheora.ogv', { ambient: true });
    } else {
        BV.show('http://example.org/video/myVideo.mp4', { altSource: 'http://example.org/video/myVideo.oggtheora.ogv', ambient: true });
    }
});
```